# set javascript input value as php variable

Tags: javascript, php

im using javascript to do some calculations on a html form. 
the result of the calculations appears correctly as expected in the input field 
name = OrderTotal

I now need the result to be stored in a php variable called $amount.

I assumed this would work $amount = $_POST[OrderTotal];

Problem is that $amount is always equal to NULL even when OrderTotal has the correct numeric value and the form is submitted.

Do i need to use ajax to ensure the updated OrderTotal value is submitted? It seems like there should be an easier way to store OrderTotal input value in a variable?

This is just a code sample - I have tried to simplify it as much as possible

```
<FORM NAME=form1 METHOD=POST ACTION="payment_page.php">
<SELECT onChange=FormatFields()>

//do the calculations by running FormatFields. 
//output the result in input NAME=OrderTotal

</SELECT>

<INPUT TYPE=Text NAME=OrderTotal id = "total" SIZE=8 value=0.00>
<?php $amount = $_POST['OrderTotal'];

?>
<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE=Submit>
</FORM>
```

Even when just hardcoding the value

```
<INPUT TYPE=Text NAME=OrderTotal id = "total" value=300>
$amount = $_POST['OrderTotal']; 
var_dump($amount);
```

$amount equals NULL not 300

Comment: Does your caps lock ever get tired?

Comment: if OrderTotal is populated client side when the form is submitted then it will be set in the POST array